# Eclipse shows compile error for every line in .asm file

Tags: assembly, eclipse-cdt

Just imported a project I'm taking over into Eclipse. I was compiling fine with g++ earlier but progress was slow as I'm more of an IDE person I decided to import all the source to Eclipse and make a new project.

Now when compiling, my .asm file has an error on every single line, as if Eclipse-CDT doesn't understand assembly code.

I'm running Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu 10.04 x86. If it helps, the assembly was written on the windows platform (I'm trying to port the project to Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Eclipse supports assembly? Is it aware that the files are in assembly? Does it know what syntax they're in?

Comment: I would assume that it knows assembly since all C / C++ code gets reduced to assembly correct? 

As I think about it more and more I get the feeling that maybe the original project assembly code is proprietary to windows and not going to port over to Linux at all?

Comment: It may not recognize .asm files as assembly files, though. Assembly files can generally have many different extensions.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Right now I'm commenting out all the assembly to see what happens. The #defines are still working which is all I need right now from each of the .asm files I think.